# Issue in using CSS to styling a vue template

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Im doing a login page and im having trouble using css to style vue templates.

Without vue i have it working, here is my code:

HTML

```
<body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

When i do the same thing in a Vue template it doesnt work because im using the tag html and body in the css. 
How can i achieve the same result (styling wise) in a vue template without using html and body tag.

Using what was recomended:

[with vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYyBF.png)

[without vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QtAe.png)

its working better then before but it still isnt working 100%, i had tried it before and this also happened, any idea on how to fix?

Comment: are you working with single file component? or just defining your component like `Vue.omponent('comp-name',{template:...})`

Comment: its a single file component

Comment: could you show how have you did that so far and the structure of your project?

Comment: its a vue cli project and this is a view, its a login.vue file, u want me to show u the code i have for the view?

Comment: did you try my solution by that wrapper and `height:100%`?

Comment: yes i responded to my post with what happened

Comment: you should edit your question with that not answering

Comment: in this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/rj1w3nrkwm) try to add your other details fork the project and give me the link

Comment: i changed it and while doing it i discovered why it was not going to the top the color, my question now is why is he only apllying the template to the top of the page? by the way bootstrap isnt working where u sent me, it isnt important tho.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your problem, please add your details to that project and give the link of the forked project

Comment: meanwhile i found the problem, i had styles in the app.vue that were messing things up (what a dumb mistake), sry for wasting your time and ty so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please read carefully documentation on how vue works. Usually vue connects to `div#app` and all going on there, so writing styles **inside** a component you can't get to body and html tags. If you really need to have these styles to those tags you can use outer CSS file and connect it to HTML. But try to avoid doing some CSS in direct index.html because later you might forget where you did this, so you will spend a **lot** of time trying to find that.

I don't see any reason to do like you want it. It's easy to do without touching html and body.